# SQLite with large data, is it best to split

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite because this is for cross-platform.  I have about 10 tables with a small amount of data (maybe a few dozen rows each), but then I also have a set of data which might have a million or more rows.

The small dataset isn't really modified that much, just queried, but the large data set will be queried and modified frequently.

Rather than have a single SQLite database with all the tables in it, I was wondering if splitting it into two databases might be smartest.

Basically I'd have one database, lets call it "settings", with the 10 tables in it.  I'd then have another database, lets call it "userdata", with the million rows.

I'll be creating a third database called "audits" where I record each change to the "userdata" database.  This database is expected to grow (for a short time period).

I am just wondering if people have an opinion as to whether it is a good idea to split my data into multiple databases or if I should just have one massive one.

My thinking is the queries on the "userdata" database might be slightly more efficient since it will only have one table.

Note, this is not for long-term.  It is for a short period of time.  It will be queried and edited for about a week, then it is done.

Comment: You do not care about our opinions, you care about the actual behaviour in your specific environment. Measure it.

Comment: Fair.  Rather than "an opinion" change it to "any experience"